# How does prime factorization guarantee that the factors will be prime?

Tags: c#, primes

In this particular code how does it not output 6 1, because 6 gives no remainder dividing 18 by it.

```
int n = 18;
int[] fact = new int[100];
int[] pow = new int[100];
int d = 0; 

for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) 
{
    int s = 0;

    while(n % i == 0)
    {
        s++; 
        n /= i;
    } 

    if (s > 0)
    {
        fact[d] = i; 
        pow[d] = s;
        d++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: "6 gives no remainder dividing it by 18" Do you mean 6 divided by 18 or 18 divided by 6? The former gives gives a remainder of 6 while the later gives a remainder of 0.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I suggest you add some print statements to see what is going on. What the code is doing is unclear to me.

Comment: I'd switch from using fixed sized arrays to lists that you add the values to.

Comment: I added print statements but that doesn't clarify this process to me

Comment: The end result is that 18 is 2 * 3 * 3. where `fact` has the values 2 and 3 and `pow` has how many times each number is a factor.  6 is not prime thus it's not included.

Comment: 6 is not included because the number is already divided by 2 and 3. 18 is divided by 2, becomes 9, 9 is divided by 3 => becomes 3, is divided by 3 and becomes 1. 1 is not divisible by anything greater than 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every numbers is either a prime, or a multiple of a prime. Look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

If it is not divisible by a prime, **it can not be divisible by any multiple of that prime either**. As 18 can be divided by 2 - 4, 6, 8, 10 and everything else never needs to be tested. As 19 can not be divided by 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10 never need to be tested. That 20 is divisible by 10, never needs to be tested. It already divides by 2 so we excluded half the possible numbers back then.

We do that exclusion of divisors instinctively, but usually only for 2 - testing only odd numbers - but you can drive that way further. As the result of a division must also be a prime or multiple of a prime, we even can stop once we passed the Squareroot.

All you really need is a unbroken list of primes, going to up to whatever Prime is > Squarroot(PrimeCandidate). Short of reading it from memory, that is the quickest way I know off.

I actually wrote something on the topic a while back, about the 5-ish ways of checking for a prime: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85fc2406-d2e9-495a-bea7-e516661f8b40/primal-issues-multithreading-lists-in-memory-and-checking-for-prime-number?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: 18 is not divisible by 4, 8 or 10.  It's divisible by 2, 3, 6, and 9 (and of course 1 and 18).

Comment: @juharr I do not really care about those numbers. **Not** having to check those numbers is the reason Prime Factorization works and is usefull.

Comment: You literally say _18 can be divided by 2 - 4, 6, 8, 10_.  I'm pointing out that is flat out wrong.  I think you mean to state that 18 can only be divisible by number less than or equal to it.

Comment: @juharr I actually said: "As 18 can be divided by 2 - 4, 6, 8, 10 and everything else **never needs to be tested.**" and " As 19 can not be divided by 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10 **never need to be tested.**"

Comment: Oh I see you mean since 18 is divisible by 2 we do not need to check 4, 6, 8, and 10.  I just found your use of - to mean 2 to 4.

Comment: @juharr I read this the same way originally. Notice the dash between the 2 and the 4. Christopher intends that to separate ideas. It probably should be a period, or some other punctuation mark to make it clear that he is stating "As 18 can be devided by 2" and "4, 6, 8, 10 and everything else never needs to be tested" as two separate thoughts.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah, sometimes knowing how to properly convey your ideas is just as important as the ideas.